# How to configure Visual studio code for c++ in ubuntu

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

How do I configure `tasks.json` for c++ ?

When I used default configuration and run a c++ code, it gives me:

```
Failed to launch external program tsc HelloWorld.ts.
spawn tsc ENOENT
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my tasks.json. I found it somewhere and it works fine for me using Make.

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "make",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "Makefile",
            // Make this the default build command.
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
            "showOutput": "always",
            // No args
            "args": ["all"],
            // Use the standard less compilation problem matcher.
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "cpp",
                "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```